# Magento does not want to find some products on frontend

Tags: magento-1.9

I ran into a problem.

I have a product that Magento does not want to find in my search on frontend, when client looking for goods, he finds almost all the goods, but some goods do not, although they are in stock and have qty
[image]

search settings are fine tuned. This problem is only in some products.

Comment: Please also check `visibility`

Comment: all my products visible, can you tell me more options?